# Function logic reuse between char string and wchar_t string without explicit string copying?

Tags: c, string, code-reuse, wchar-t, memory-optimization

I'm writing a data structure in C to store commands; Here is the source pared down to what I'm unsatisfied with:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include "dbg.h"
#include "commandtree.h"

struct BranchList
{
    CommandTree *tree;
    BranchList *next;
};

struct CommandTree
{
    wchar_t id;       // wchar support actually has no memory cost due to the 
    bool term;        // padding that would otherwise exist, and may in fact be
    BranchList *list; // marginally faster to access due to its alignable size.
};

static inline BranchList *BranchList_create(void)
{
    return calloc(1, sizeof(BranchList));
}

inline CommandTree *CommandTree_create(void)
{
    return calloc(1, sizeof(CommandTree));
}

int CommandTree_putnw(CommandTree *t, const wchar_t *s, size_t n)
{
    for(BranchList **p = &t->list;;)
    {
        if(!*p)
        {

            *p = BranchList_create();
            if(errno == ENOMEM) return 1;
            (*p)->tree = CommandTree_create();
            if(errno == ENOMEM) return 1;
            (*p)->tree->id = *s;
        }   
        else if(*s != (*p)->tree->id)
        {   
            p = &(*p)->next;
            continue;
        }
        if(n == 1)
        {
            (*p)->tree->term = 1;
            return 0;
        }
        p = &(*p)->tree->list;
        s++;
        n--;

    }
}
int CommandTree_putn(CommandTree *t, const char *s, size_t n)
{
    wchar_t *passto = malloc(n * sizeof(wchar_t));
    mbstowcs(passto, s, n);
    int ret = CommandTree_putnw(t, passto, n);
     free(passto);
    return ret;
}
```

This works perfectly well, but I'm rather unsatisfied with how I'm handling the fact that my tree supports `wchar_t`. I decided to add this when I realized that the padding of `CommandTree` would make any datatype smaller than than 7 bytes cost just as much memory anyway, but so as not to duplicate code, I have `CommandTree_putn` reuse the logic in the wchar_t-supporting `CommandTree_putnw`.

However, due to the difference in size of `char` and `wchar_t`, I can't just pass the array; I have to convert using `mbstowcs` and pass a temporary `wchar_t *` to `CommandTree_putnw`. This is suboptimal, given that `CommandTree_putn` is going to see the most usage and this quintuples the memory usage (`sizeof (char)` to `sizeof (char) + sizeof (wchar_t)`) of the stored string, which could stack if lots of these are going to be instantiated with longish commands.

I was wondering it I could do something like create a third function that would contain the logic, and get passed a `size_t`, depending in the value of which it would cast the string passed to it as a `void *` to either `const char *` or `const wchar_t *` but given that C is statically typed, I'd have to pretty much duplicate the logic with `s` cast to its respective type, which would ruin the idea I'm going for of "single instance of logic".

So ultimately, the question is, can I provide the program logic only once and pass wrappers `const char *` and `const wchar_t *` respectively, without creating a temporary `wchar_t *` in the function to handle `const char *`?

Comment: You should cut that huge paragraph into separate sentences, in order to make the reading easier!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know your hard requirements, but `wchar_t` tends to be difficult to work with precisely because of this problem; it's too hard to mesh with existing code that uses `char`.

All of the codebases I've worked with eventually migrated to UTF-8, which removes the necessity to store strings in a different type. UTF-8 works with the standard `strcpy`/`strlen` type of string manipulation functions and is fully Unicode savvy. The only challenge is that you will need to convert it to UTF-16 to invoke Windows Unicode APIs. (OS X can use UTF-8 directly.) You didn't mention platform so I don't know if this will be an issue for you. In our case we just wrote Win32 wrappers that took UTF-8 strings.

Can you use C++? If so, and the actual type `wchar_t` is important (rather than Unicode support), you can templatize the functions and then instantiate them with `std::wstring` or `std::string` depending on string width. You can also write them to be based on `char` and `wchar_t` if you are brave, but you'll need to write special wrapper functions to handle basic operations like `strcpy` versus `wcscpy` and so it ends up being more work overall by far.

In plain C, I don't think there's a silver bullet at all. There are yucky answers, but none I could recommend with a straight face.

Comment: I like the idea of pure UTF-8, but isn't standard practise for C to use wchar_t to store UTF-8 anyway? How would I refactor my existing code in that case?

Platform-wise, the set of POSIX-compliant OSes is my primary target; Windows porting would be more of an afterthought.

Comment: UTF-8 is always stored in 8-bit `char`, never in `wchar_t`. If you are targeting POSIX you really don't have any need for `wchar_t` at all. POSIX APIs don't use it.

Comment: Ah, okay. So I can cut the widechar methods altogether?

Comment: I second the suggestion to use UTF-8 for everything and convert to other formats only when you need to call outside code.

Comment: In code that works heavily with WinAPI it seems weird to call a function to get a utf-16 string, convert to utf-8, pass to another function, convert back ton utf-16 and call another WinAPI func. So my WinAPI code tends to be a bit of a mix of the two which is annoying.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy man.. I just concluded everything in #5 after trying various things and ending up in messes.. wish I had read that first :X  Except my compiler doesn't have the `fstream` extension working, I have to use `_wfopen` and make my own raii wrapper.